# Is it possible to get remote access of any android device from web?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, socket.io, remote-access

I'm creating an app for remote access of android device from web. so anyone have idea how I get remote access in android? I'm using socket.io and Node.js in back-end. or Is there any other technology that can help me to do this task?

Comment: What does it mean 'remote access'? What exactly are you trying to do on the phone? Do you want to access everything (like with TeamViewer for instance)?

Comment: @Eselfar yes, I'm creating an app like teamviewer where whole android phone can be controlled from the web

Comment: it is not possible to do that through a web app. You at least will need to install the native app on the device

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes. I'm also creating android app for that. but, don't know how to get remote access from android side in that app?

Answer (score -1):

Yes through **JavascriptInterface** you can invoke native functionaly of app from web. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface) you can found more about it and implementation from  [here](http://www.codexpedia.com/android/javascript-interface-for-android-and-javascript-communication/). Rest you can do from android side. Here are few links of webview with sockets.

[link 1](http://foretribe.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-make-android-webview-support.html)

[link 2](https://www.codevog.com/blog/2015-03-09-webview-interactions-with-javascript)

Comment: Can you please add the relevant parts of the pages you've linked, at least for future reference?

Comment: The question was how to access a device remotely from a browser on a desktop system not to imitate app features on a web view. The links you've provided show how to implement a web view which is completely different from the question asked. The ideal way would be to stream screen captured data to a vnc server and display that on the browser. There may also be other ways to do it.